# IE , Why ellipsis in kendo dropdownlist is phone icon?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

[View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFm7M.jpg)

My Kendo Version 2015.1.429.440

When text in kendo dropdownlist is too long

How do i have hide phone icon  or replace phone icon to ellipsis in kendo dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your sample code so I am not sure how you reference the Kendo JS files and what actual code you are using for the dropdown list.

I try to make a test using code below and it looks like it is working fine in the IE 11 browser.

Please note that I just pass **2015.1.429** instead of **2015.1.429.440** while adding the reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Demo Grid App</title>
      <!-- CDN-based stylesheet reference for Kendo UI DataViz -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
      <!-- CDN-based script reference for jQuery; utilizing a local reference if offline -->
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- CDN-based script reference for Kendo UI DataViz; utilizing a local reference if offline -->
      <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.429/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         .k-list-container{
         min-width:126px !important;
         width: auto!important;
         }
         .k-list
         {
         width:auto !important;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1>Demo dropdown App</h1>
      </header>
      <select id="drop" >
         <option>Option1</option>
         <option>Demo text Demo text Demo text</option>
      </select>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#drop").kendoDropDownList();
         });
      </script>
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

If the issue persists then I suggest you post your sample code that can help us to reproduce the issue. We will try to check and try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: I'm sure it's :   text-overflow: ellipsis;   thank you

Comment: Can you please explain in detail? Your comment is unclear to me.